# rails server successfully, but can't access the web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I successfully installed Ruby 2.1.3, Rails 4.1.6, mysql, mysql2 on my linux server(centos6.4) and then created a new project named 'hello'.

```
rails new hello -d=mysql

cd hello

rails server

=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 4.1.6 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`

=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

[2014-10-01 15:51:07] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1

[2014-10-01 15:51:07] INFO  ruby 2.1.3 (2014-09-19) [i686-linux]

[2014-10-01 15:51:07] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=30770 port=3000
```

but when I typed `http://x.x.x.x:3000` in the browser, the website created by rails can not be accessible

Comment: Did you type **exactly that URL** into your browser, or did you actually substitute `x`es for the server's IP address?

Comment: Is it the port 3000 open on your server for access? Can you curl from the server itself? `curl http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: the iptables only enables port for ssh... Now i insert the 3000 port, and everything goes well!  thx!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see the page under the following URLS:

- `http://localhost:3000/`
- `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

Comment: curl http://localhost:3000/ or http://127.0.0.1:3000/ is OK.  I checked, it's the problem of my iptables which enables 3000 port. So I can't access it. Thank U so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into your "database.yml" file, there check your DB name, user name and password are matching your local database credentials, may it will solve your issue.